# Error _LAMBDA_LOG_FD in AWS lambda function with nodejs 4.3

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, runtime-error, aws-lambda

i have an error with AWS lambda function with nodejs 4.3,

```
[ERROR] (get_int_from_env@src/lambda/runtime.c:493 errno: None) temp_str = getenv(env_name) failed.
[ERROR] (get_int_from_env@src/lambda/runtime.c:493 errno: None) temp_str = getenv(env_name) failed.
[ERROR] (runtime_init@src/lambda/runtime.c:532 errno: None) ((fd =get_int_from_env("_LAMBDA_LOG_FD", 1))) >= 0 failed. invalid file descriptor -1 
[ERROR] (runtime_init@src/lambda/runtime.c:560 errno: None) Runtime internal error
```

I think _LAMBDA_LOG_FD is environment variable set internally that indicates the file descriptor for logging.
I did not found anything in the documetation 
[here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html#lambda-environment-variables)!

For information, my lambda function uses cluster with fork process.

Someone can give a clue to resolve this issue ? Do you need more informations? and if yes , which one?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I am getting same issue in zappa python. Did you find any solution??

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this issue in python flask.

I have resolved it by changing main function.

Previously main function was defined as

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.run()
```

I have **replaced** it with

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

one more thing **parameter_depth** variable added in "zappa_settings.json" file.

```
{
    "dev": {
        "app_function": "run.app", 
        "s3_bucket": "Your_bucket_name",
        "parameter_depth":1
    }
}
```